# Può "essere permessi" essere considerato valido?

Tags: grammar

Una frase certamente valida è:

> Non ho il permesso di farlo.

la forma riflessiva, invece:

> Non posso permettermi di farlo.

Leggendo [perméttere](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/permettere/), è citata una sua versione riflessiva (punto b)

> la debolezza non gli permette di alzarsi dal letto

Domanda: **sarebbe grammaticalmente corretto usare una versione indiretta di tale riflessione**?  Ossia

> Egli non *è permesso di* alzarsi dal letto a causa della debolezza.
>
> Io non sono permesso di farlo.

In entrambi i casi, perché?
La seconda frase è piuttosto ambigua ma, leggermente meno, la prima.

Comment: Dov'è la costruzione riflessiva di “permettere” in «la debolezza non gli permette di alzarsi dal letto»?

Comment: Unicamente nella forma negativa puoi usare il verbo `impossibilitare`: `Io sono impossibilitato a ...` Non è estremamente diffuso, ma è corretto.

Comment: Uno steroide, un anabolizzante e un succo di frutta incontrano il medico sportivo al bar. Lo steroide indica il succo di frutta dicendo "egli e' permesso".

Comment: @TobiaTesan Buon esempio (corretto). Ma cosa alludevi dire specificamente?

Comment: E' l'unico (delirante) esempio che mi viene in mente in cui "egli e' permesso" sia ammissibile - normalmente trovo difficile che una *persona* (in questo caso e' la *personificazione* di una cosa) sia *oggetto* di divieto o meno. In Italiano, il soggetto di "permettere" (o ammettere, o consentire) in forma passiva (o l'oggetto, se in forma attiva) e' la *cosa che e' o meno permessa*.

Comment: In effetti sarebbe "esso è permesso" perché non ci riferiamo ad una persona. Comunque, mi piacerebbe leggere una tua risposta dove esponi la tua corretta interpretazione.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Le due frasi sono “scorrette” (nel senso che non trovano riscontro nell'uso grammaticale italiano).

Quanto al perché, ovviamente è più facile dimostrare la correttezza di una costruzione (esibendone esempi da autori classici o da opere di consultazione) che non la sua scorrettezza, ma ragionerei così, con una specie di dimostrazione per assurdo:

- consideriamo la frase di cui parliamo: «egli non è permesso di alzarsi dal letto a causa della debolezza»; qui “egli” è il soggetto di “(non) è permesso”;
- quindi, nella corrispondente costruzione attiva, “egli” dovrebbe essere il complemento oggetto di “permette”: «(qualcuno, o la debolezza etc.) non lo permette di alzarsi»;
- ma il verbo “permettere” usato transitivamente (dove l'oggetto è una subordinata o raramente un nome) richiede che il complemento oggetto sia la cosa permessa, come in «non permetto che si fumi», «l’ufficiale permise ai soldati una sosta di poche ore» ([Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/permettere/)).

Qed. Se vogliamo esprimere quel concetto in forma passiva, semmai avremo una struttura del tipo «la cosa X non è permessa alla persona Y dal fatto/persona Z» («alzarsi dal letto non gli è permesso dalla debolezza», che non suona meravigliosamente ma è coerente con il modo in cui si costruisce “permettere”).

Più in generale, se un verbo ammette un complemento oggetto e un complemento di termine (“io permetto la sosta ai soldati”, “Gino dà una mela a Dina”, “la maestra insegna le tabelline agli scolari”), è il complemento oggetto che diventerà soggetto delle rispettive forme passive (“la sosta è permessa ai soldati da me”, “una mela è data da Gino a Dina”, “le tabelline vengono insegnate agli scolari dalla maestra”) e non il complemento di termine (*“i soldati sono permessi...”, *“Dina è data...”, *“gli scolari sono insegnati...”).

Comment: Grazie per le informazioni. L'unica risposta qualificabile come tale.

Answer (score 4):

No, è una costruzione probabilmente presa in prestito dall'inglese ma che non trova posto in italiano, fatto salvo forse per eventuali regionalismi, di cui comunque non ho notizia.

Qualunque madrelingua con una sensibilità linguistica anche media te lo può confermare e credo che non sia necessario investigare oltre. Sul perché, la motivazione è la stessa che rende sbagliata la frase "il co-creatore dei Simpson Sam Simon muore invecchiato 59".

Answer (score 2):

Le versioni corrette sono

> Non gli è permesso (di) alzarsi dal letto...
>
> Non mi è permesso (di) farlo

oppure, se si vuole sottolineare la persona oggetto della proibizione:

> A lui non è permesso (di) alzarsi dal letto... (ma a un altro sì)
>
> A me non è permesso (di) farlo (invece a Mario sì)

Se si vuole enfatizzare specialmente l'atto della proibizione in sé, si può usare

> Non gli viene permesso ...

Il significato è simile, ma qui il lettore o ascoltatore può quasi immaginare qualcuno o qualcosa che attivamente impedisce l'azione.

Comment: Che siano corrette è certo. Però io sto chiedendo *un altro tipo di utilizzo*; ti invito a rileggere la mia domanda.

Comment: Le frasi che proponi in fondo alla tua domanda non sono corrette. Le versioni corrette per esprimere il concetto che vuoi esprimere sono quelle che ho scritto io.

Comment: Di nuovo, concordo che siano corrette. Però, che tu dica siano corrette/errate, non è sufficiente: devi aggiungere qualche riferimento. 
A me sembrano inusuali, ma come forma indiretta della terzultima frase sembrano plausibili. Spero di essermi spiegato...

Comment: Forse non mi sono spiegato: *LE TUE* non sono corrette. "Permesso" come aggettivo si può applicare a un'azione o attività: "la caccia non è permessa" etc. Non si può dire di una persona che "è permessa" o "non è permessa". Se queste forme ti sembrano plausibili e sei madrelingua, sono curioso di sapere di dove sei.

Comment: Mai detto che lo siano (altrimenti perché chiederlo?). Mi spiace per il fraintendimento. 
Comunque, ancora, che siano incorrette è probabile, però mi aspetto *concrete* fonti.

Comment: (Mia ultima risposta) La mia fonte è che sono madrelingua. Non credo che un inglese abbia bisogno di fonti per sapere che "I not go" non è corretta.

Comment: Beh, allora non avrai problema a *provare* che siano sbagliate. Per me la risposta attuale è lontana dall'essere completa, poi a te la scelta.

Comment: @karoshi Un inglese può sempre fare riferimento alla regola per spiegare perchè si dice "I don't go". [è legittimo](http://italian.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) chiedere "fonti e spiegazioni autorevoli".

Comment: In questo caso si applica il Rasoio di Occam. Non voglio perdere tempo a dimostrare perché "siamo stati insegnati di scrivere" è sbagliato. L'ipotesi secondo cui la frase dell'OP è corretta è un'ipotesi non necessaria e visto che si tratterebbe praticamente di un hapax sta a lui, nel caso, dimostrarne l'utilità e la spendibilità linguistica.